# Most efficient data data structure for array with 2 different types

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, data-structures

Working in Java with multidimensional arrays which have 3 columns of two data types - Column1 can be of any primitive data type, Column2 and Column3 are integers of the same size. We have thousands of these arrays with many lookup and comparison operations so we would like to see if there are faster/smaller alternatives to arrays of type object. We need to maintain the sort order and want to avoid hashing. All operations use all 3 columns.

Summarizing the requirements:
 1. Maximize speed of iterating through the data structure
 2. Minimize the size of the data structure
 3. Maintain the sort order of the array contents
 4. Avoid hashing (no LinkedHashMap)

Structures we have considered thus far:
 1. Object array (current implementation)
 2. Make 2 arrays (one for each data type) and during operations join them by array index lookup

Does anyone have any other (better) recommendation for data structure? Thanks :)

Comment: @ɐuıɥɔɐɯ Thanks for your suggestion. However we need to maintain the sort order (the arrays are joined with each other this way) so ordinary hashing is not an option. We tried LinkedHashMap but this was far slower than an array of type object. Would like other alternatives

Comment: Why is java so important here? I would use a mature relational database, like postgres.

Comment: @TamasRev we are actually creating backend storage for a relational database, this is for DBMS research

Comment: @WillGetItDunn aw, I see. I'm not on the same league with this question then :)

Comment: @TamasRev that was a good suggestion though!

Comment: @gpasch no we're just 3 people doing research, we don't have consultants

Comment: In most cases where people ask about dealing with parallel arrays the most useful thing is having a single array of Objects -- some new Object that carries the information that would be in the parallel arrays.  Here it would have 3 attributes: an Object that carries a primitive type and the 2 integers. But since you're talking DBMS back-end this may not be sensible, for space or performance reasons ... but think about combining these 3 things into some kind of structure.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would - naively - implement an RDBMS

- Use an array of byte array: `byte[][]` and an external class that knows how to implement the byte arrays.
- There can be markers in the byte array, like defining type for the first item. I.e. markers for the 8 primitive types (`byte`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `float`, `double`, `boolean`, `char`) can easily fit into 1 byte.
- You can use B-trees (aka indexes) to make lookup faster
- If the order of items can be virtual, then another index can do that too

I believe you guys already know this. But I'm curious if there's anything new out there.